# How can I specify the required Node.js version in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package, version

I have a Node.js project that requires Node version 12 or higher. Is there a way to specify this in the `packages.json` file, so that the installer will automatically check and inform the users if they need to upgrade?

Comment: A similar way to Adam's response, also using node.version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48691987/3032209

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enforce a specific node.js version to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409883/how-to-enforce-a-specific-node-js-version-to-use)

Comment: Question was already asked here: How to enforce a specific node.js version to use?

Comment: I wonder if there is any tool that can automatically set this field to an appropriate value by inspecting API usage.

Comment: NOTE: If using `yarn` version 2+, you will need to install the yarn engines plugin found here: https://github.com/devoto13/yarn-plugin-engines

Answer (score 952, accepted):

You can set the `engines` field in your `package.json` and set requirements for either `node` or `npm` versions or both:

```json
  "engines" : { 
    "npm" : ">=8.0.0 <9.0.0",
    "node" : ">=16.0.0 <17.0.0"
  }
```

To enforce this via npm you need to create an `.npmrc` file (and commit it to the repository) and set the `engine-strict` option to `true`, which will cause npm commands such as `npm install` to fail if the required engine versions to not match:

```ini
# .npmrc
engine-strict=true
```

Without that file, every developer will need to run `npm config set engine-strict true` in their local workspace to switch on this option.

## Original Answer

As you're saying your code definitely won't work with any lower versions, you probably want the "engineStrict" flag too:

```
{ "engineStrict" : true }
```

Documentation for the package.json file can be found [on the npmjs site](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines)

**Update**

`engineStrict` is now deprecated, so this will only give a warning. It's now down to the user to run `npm config set engine-strict true` if they want this.

**Update 2**

As ben pointed out below, creating a `.npmrc` file at the root of your project (the same level as your package.json file) with the text `engine-strict=true` will force an error during installation if the Node version is not compatible.

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#enginestrict

"The rarely-used package.json option `engineStrict` has been **deprecated** 
for several months, producing warnings when it was used. Starting with 
npm@3, the value of the field is ignored, and engine violations will only 
produce warnings. If you, as a user, want strict engines field enforcement, just run npm config set engine-strict true"

Comment: Remember to `cd .. && npm i <folder-name>` in order to check for the project itself. However, this will trigger a whole build in it self.

Comment: why on earth they deprecated that.. it looses all its meaning then

Comment: Adding `engine-strict=true` to your .npmrc now has the same effect

Comment: @ben Perfect, thank you! And this can be committed so that at least your entire team is required to adhere to the engine version requirements.

Comment: @MikeStead that deprecation is for the package.json directive `engineStrict` and not the user-configurable `engine-strict` setting for NPM

Comment: @Joe erm yep I was replying to this answer (in 2015) which mentioned `engineStrict` specifically and my reply also mentioned the alternative `engine-strict` npm config option.

Comment: I dont't get a warning on windows when `engine-strict=false` and `{ "engineStrict" : true }`

Comment: Just to be clear, adding `engine-strict=true` to *your own* .npmrc file does not enforce anything for your end user, it only enforces you to use the right engine for the packages that *you* install. There’s nothing you can do to enforce that *your end users* use the right engine, short of you telling them to add the setting to *their* .npmrc file.

Comment: `npm install` respects `engine=strict` but `yarn install` ignores it

Comment: must be `>=12` not `>=0.12`

Comment: how can i set this with yarn

Comment: But how do I know the minimum required node version of the node proejct I've made? Please let me know if anyone has a clue. thanks.

Comment: May I know what is the deal with node version in `package.json` shown as `0.10.0` but in CLI it says `10.0.x`?

Comment: This doesn't work without also adding node-version to your .npmrc. E.g. `node-version = >=14.0.0||<15.0.0`. This will prevent `npm i` from running if the user is not using `node 14` for example. The only downside is npm complains about semver matching: `npm WARN invalid config Must be full valid SemVer string`. Not a major issue, this still works.

Answer (score 347):

Add the following to `package.json`:

```json
"engines": {
  "npm": ">=8.0.0 <9.0.0",
  "node": ">=16.0.0 <17.0.0"
},
```

Add the following to `.npmrc` (same directory as `package.json`):

```
engine-strict=true
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution that gives the end user a nice fat error about not having the right version of node when they run `npm install`; works with `yarn` as well

Comment: This seems to have no effect at all. I set up my `package.json` with an "engines" section similar to the above (`11.13.0` and `6.7.0`), and a `.npmrc` with nothing but content specified above. I had nvm switch me to an older node version, then ran `npm install`, but it just installs the dependencies and doesn't even mention the engine version mismatch.

Comment: Adding `engine-strict=true` to *your* .npmrc file only enforces *you* to use the right engine when *you* install packages. **It does not enforce anything for your end user.** If you want your users to use the engines listed under the `"engines: {}"` property in your package.json when they install it, you should tell *them* to add `engine-strict=true` to *their* .npmrc file.

Comment: @chharvey you could add to the `package.json` the script `"preinstall": "echo 'engine-strict=true' >> .npmrc"`

Comment: `engine-strict` usage in `.npmrc` is currently not supported by direnv's `.envrc` https://github.com/direnv/direnv/wiki/Node (Found '.nvmrc' with version `engine-strict=true`N/A: version "engine-strict=true -> N/A" is not yet installed.

Answer (score 76):

Just like said Ibam, `engineStrict` is now deprecated. But I've found this solution:

**check-version.js:**

```
import semver from 'semver';
import { engines } from './package';

const version = engines.node;
if (!semver.satisfies(process.version, version)) {
  console.log(`Required node version ${version} not satisfied with current version ${process.version}.`);
  process.exit(1);
}
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "my package",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=50.9" // intentionally so big version number
  },
  "scripts": {
    "requirements-check": "babel-node check-version.js",
    "postinstall": "npm run requirements-check"
  }
}
```

Find out more here: 
https://medium.com/@adambisek/how-to-check-minimum-required-node-js-version-4a78a8855a0f#.3oslqmig4

***.nvmrc***

And one more thing.
A dotfile '.nvmrc' can be used for requiring specific node version - https://github.com/creationix/nvm#nvmrc

But, it is only respected by npm scripts (and yarn scripts).

Comment: This is the best answer in 2019, in light of set engine deprecation and the reality that many are (likely) encountering this due to switching versions with nvm.

Comment: This assumes @babel/node is installed.

Answer (score 67):

**`.nvmrc`**

If you are [using NVM like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm/971612#971612), which you likely should, then you can indicate the nodejs version required for given project in a git-tracked `.nvmrc` file:

```
node --version > .nvmrc
```

or:

```
echo v10.15.1 > .nvmrc
```

This does not take effect automatically on `cd`, which is sane: the user must then do a:

```
nvm use
```

and now that version of node will be used for the current shell.

You can list the versions of node that you have with:

```
nvm list
```

`.nvmrc` is documented at: https://github.com/creationix/nvm/tree/02997b0753f66c9790c6016ed022ed2072c22603#nvmrc

How to automatically select that node version on `cd` was asked at: [Automatically switch to correct version of Node based on project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653036/automatically-switch-to-correct-version-of-node-based-on-project)

Tested with NVM 0.33.11.

**`.nvmrc` vs package.json `engines`**

What you might want to do is:

- use [`engines` in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29349773/895245) to give a "no known incompatibilities range"
- give  the `.nvmrc` to set a "tested with"

much like package.json vs package-lock.json.

**Heroku does respect package.json `engines:`**

Worth mentioning, as [documented here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version), Heroku does play it nice and obey the `engines:` entry e.g.:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.17.0",
    "npm": "6.14.13"
  },
```

So you should [Always, Always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71065040/heroku-shopify-application-error-npm-err-eresolve-unable-to-resolve-dependency/71112052#71112052) set that to what you are using locally.

This had been previously mentioned on this [self deleted answer to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42864292/895245).

Comment: `nvm use` doesn't pick up .nvmrc for nvm version 1.1.7

Comment: @AakashVerma hmmm, on a quick look nvm only goes to version 0.37.2, and nvmrc is still documented on master: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/tree/436cda247e1f5f96bf20df8d49f968dd4d3a9523#nvmrc let me know if you figure it out.

Comment: @AakashVerma I'm guessing you're using https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases As mentioned on their README "The original nvm is a completely separate project for Mac/Linux only. This project uses an entirely different philosophy and is not just a clone of nvm" so it's not surprising. Consider opening a feature request on their tracker.

Comment: Seems there's a recent PR waiting for this https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/pull/594

Answer (score 18):

There's another, simpler way to do this:

1. `npm install Node@8` (saves Node 8 as dependency in package.json)
2. Your app will run using Node 8 for **anyone** - even Yarn users!

This works because `node` is just a package that ships node as its package binary. It just  includes as node_module/.bin which means it only makes node available to package scripts. Not main shell.

See discussion on Twitter here: https://twitter.com/housecor/status/962347301456015360

Comment: I disagree, this would potentially hide the issue and would sideload a different version of node if it wasn't installed.

Comment: -1 because this is terrible (really terrible) idea. It's like saying that if you are unemployed you should fund a company first and you can start working there.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea to me. Separate node versions for separate projects. Can safely upgrade one without upgrading the others. Only catch is have to run in .bin `./node node-sass` rather than just `node-sass`. Not sure if same for all .bin files.

Comment: This is a simple and elegant solution - as long as the team members working on the product know this is happening, I think it's a great answer.

We are using this technique at a large company to deal with the variety of Node versions for a dozen web front-end products.  Removes the need for constant switching with nvm when going back and forth between products.

Comment: This solution has its own pros and cons. Node version encapsulation is potentially its biggest pro. The downside is bloated docker image size if you are going to deploy it this way.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something but, couldn't this be installed as a 'dev' dependency, so `npm I -D Node@8`, I'm guessing it wouldn't (shouldn't) then be bundled into a Docker image (or executable), which would simply provide it's own NodeJS runtime, right?

Comment: @Brendan Hannemann ，why would it not being installed? shouldn't you always run `npm install` at least once before running the app? This is the best solution IMHO as it's basically packaging a virtual environment with the app which means it will always run with exactly the same nodejs environment for everyone as long as `npm install` finished successfully.

Comment: Does this account for node requirements in dependencies? F.e. node-sass and many other libs uses/builds different executables for different node versions, if install performed under node 8 and package.json depends on node 16, would then node-sass be built for node 16, or node 8? If node dependency restriction is accounted in other dependencies, then this might be a convenient trick.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my complete ready-to-use script, based on [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41620850/277304).

`check-version.js` :

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
const fs = require('fs');
const semver = require('semver');
const childProcess = require('child_process');

// checks that current node and npm versions satisfies requirements in package.json
// to run manually:   node check-version.js [verbose]

const VERBOSE_FORCED = false;    
const args = process.argv.slice(2);
const VERBOSE = VERBOSE_FORCED || (args.length > 0 && args[0] === 'verbose');

const printErrAndExit = (x) => {
  console.error(x);
  console.error('Aborting');
  process.exit(1);
};

const checkNpmVersion = (npmVersionRequired) => {
  if (!npmVersionRequired) {
    console.log('No required npm version specified');
    return;
  }
  const npmVersion = `${childProcess.execSync('npm -v')}`.trim();
  if (VERBOSE) console.log(`npm required: '${npmVersionRequired}' - current: '${npmVersion}'`);
  if (!semver.satisfies(npmVersion, npmVersionRequired)) {
    printErrAndExit(`Required npm version '${npmVersionRequired}' not satisfied. Current: '${npmVersion}'.`);
  }
};

const checkNodeVersion = (nodeVersionRequired) => {
  if (!nodeVersionRequired) {
    console.log('No required node version specified');
    return;
  }
  const nodeVersion = process.version;
  if (VERBOSE) console.log(`node required: '${nodeVersionRequired}' - current: '${nodeVersion}'`);
  if (!semver.satisfies(nodeVersion, nodeVersionRequired)) {
    printErrAndExit(`Required node version '${nodeVersionRequired}' not satisfied. Current: '${nodeVersion}'.`);
  }
};

const json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json'));
if (!json.engines) printErrAndExit('no engines entry in package json?');
checkNodeVersion(json.engines.node);
checkNpmVersion(json.engines.npm);
```

It should be placed in the root project directory.

It checks node and/or npm version, as specified in `package.json` (`engines` entry), eg

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0 <17.0.0",
    "npm": ">=8.0.0 <9.0.0"
  },
```

You can invoke it manually as

`node check-version.js [verbose]`

or include it as script inside `package json`, either as standalone script or as a prerequisite for other scripts, eg

```
"scripts" : {
  "start": "node check-version.js && vite",
  "build": "node check-version.js && vite build",
  "lint": "node check-version.js && eslint .",
  "check-version": "node check-version.js verbose"
},
```

Comment: but this cannot prevent user running `npm install` right?

Answer (score -1):

A Mocha test case example:

```
describe('Check version of node', function () {
    it('Should test version assert', async function () {

            var version = process.version;
            var check = parseFloat(version.substr(1,version.length)) > 12.0;
            console.log("version: "+version);
            console.log("check: " +check);         
            assert.equal(check, true);
    });});
```

Comment: Should not be a unit test, use package.json /dotfiles

Comment: But whhhhhhhy, a unit test is designed for this >.-

Comment: Because you need Node to run a unit test. If the node version present is too outdated, the tests will simply not run or they'll fail with syntax error or smth. similar, which defeats the point of unit testing. It's like hiding a password reset form behind an authorization form. If you can't remember the password, you need to use reset password function, but now you can't use it, because you don't remember the password.

Comment: My assumption being there is at least a minimal packages installed. why else enforce a specific one.

Comment: @JamieNicholl-Shelley Nooooo! unit-test not designed for that! Did you see how go.mod specify the version of go, ... pom.xml specify the version of java! we need the saaaame! got it?

Comment: How so? It needs to execute and blocks the runtime if fail. PLus, I mean it's a node project, if you haven't got node installed.. well good luck to you

Comment: Sorry, I down voted this answer, because a unit test doesn't make any sense for this.

Comment: @Jose4Linux I don't see how condisering node checks are always done on build time with includes unit tests, but ok.

Comment: @ankhzet 's explanation is pretty clear.

Comment: unit tests can be invoked by any number of ways, plus node version control is different to check if it is installd completely - fairly obvious if you don't. So no, it is not clear.

Comment: As a number of node runtimes grows (deno.js, bun.js, ts-node etc.) this "unit" test becomes even more useless =D And again, OP asked about a fail-safe for an _installer_. Tests are run _after_ an installation already completed, at best. You have a chicken and an egg problem here.

Comment: As others have pointed out, a unit test doesn't make any sense. Basically you're saying install this package to know you can't install this package. Does not compute.

Comment: As stated previously, this is perfectly useful code as it allow version upgraded to be flagged. If you haven't got any version installed, well that's a litmus test for if you should be allowed near keyboard...