# Automatically switch to correct version of Node based on project

Tags: node.js, nvm

Let's say I have 2 projects:

```
example1: requires node version 0.12.1
example2: requires node version 0.10
```

Currently, when I `cd` into each project, I use `nvm use <version>` before running the application.

Is there a way with node or nvm, to automatically switch to the needed version of node when I `cd` into each project?

Comment: Doubt it. You could however have a npm run that does it.

Comment: You could setup a bash script and call from there. Plausible

Answer (score 38):

Looks for a `.nvmrc` file in your current directory, every time you `cd`. If one is found, it loads the version via `nvm use` and throws out any output.

```bsh
cd() {
  builtin cd "$@"
  if [[ -f .nvmrc ]]; then
    nvm use > /dev/null
  fi
}
cd .
```

Comment: Nice and easy, the best of all. Thanks

Comment: Note that the code snippet that is provided in the answer should be placed in the `~/.zshrc` file if you are using ZSH terminal. And the `.nvmrc` file should be placed in the root of your project directory. Also, the content that you need to add to the `.nvmrc` is the Node version that you want to use (like: `v14.21.1` for example).

Comment: Seems like you don't have to do this anymore.  nvm will auto switch the node version in your directory if it finds a `.nvrmc` file.  Doing  `node -v > .nvmrc` will create one with a current node version in your project.

Answer (score 17):

Install Automatic Node Version Switching ([avn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/avn)) and add `.node-version` file that specifies the version you'd like to use with project. It automatically detects and uses it via installed version manager such as `nvm` and `n`.

Comment: This project's owner is no longer maintaining avn and so this solution will not work on Ubuntu; you will get an error when you attempt to set it up.

Comment: Same on mac by the look of it, however @illnr solution for zsh works great.

Answer (score 17):

You can add nvm command into package.json file

```
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "nvm install 0.12.1",
  "prestart": "nvm use 0.12.1",
  "start": "node ./file1.js"
},
```

Also set desired version into package.json, so Continuous Integration services would know what version you want to use.

```
{
  "name": "naive",
  "description": "A package using naive versioning",
  "author": "A confused individual <iam@confused.com>",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": ">= 1.2.0",
    "optimist": ">= 0.1.0"
  },
  "engine": "node 0.4.1"
}
```

Comment: When I run `npm install` it fails to run the first command and says `nvm command not found`. `nvm` is installed and I can run the command from shell.

Comment: I have the same issue that @ajay has reported above

Comment: @ajay You need to execute `nvm.sh` file first. Example `sh ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm use 14.15.4`.

Comment: This is not working for me. Not even Laode's suggestion. I am using .zshrc and macosx but need it to be cross platform.

Console prints following:
`> sh ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm use 12.18.3
sh: nvm: command not found`

Comment: If you still have problems running nvm, add the scripts like this
`"preinstall": ". ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install 0.12.1",`
`"predev": ". ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm use 0.12.1",`

Answer (score 13):

There are also extended (user contributed) bash/zsh shell scripts in the [NVM GitHub README](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#bash):

#### bash script

> **Automatically call `nvm use`**
>   This alias would search 'up' from your current directory in order to detect a `.nvmrc` file. If it finds it, it will switch to that version; if not, it will use the default version.
>
> Put the following at the end of your `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```sh
find-up () {
    path=$(pwd)
    while [[ "$path" != "" && ! -e "$path/$1" ]]; do
        path=${path%/*}
    done
    echo "$path"
}

cdnvm(){
    cd "$@";
    nvm_path=$(find-up .nvmrc | tr -d '[:space:]')

    # If there are no .nvmrc file, use the default nvm version
    if [[ ! $nvm_path = *[^[:space:]]* ]]; then

        declare default_version;
        default_version=$(nvm version default);

        # If there is no default version, set it to `node`
        # This will use the latest version on your machine
        if [[ $default_version == "N/A" ]]; then
            nvm alias default node;
            default_version=$(nvm version default);
        fi

        # If the current version is not the default version, set it to use the default version
        if [[ $(nvm current) != "$default_version" ]]; then
            nvm use default;
        fi

        elif [[ -s $nvm_path/.nvmrc && -r $nvm_path/.nvmrc ]]; then
        declare nvm_version
        nvm_version=$(<"$nvm_path"/.nvmrc)

        declare locally_resolved_nvm_version
        # `nvm ls` will check all locally-available versions
        # If there are multiple matching versions, take the latest one
        # Remove the `->` and `*` characters and spaces
        # `locally_resolved_nvm_version` will be `N/A` if no local versions are found
        locally_resolved_nvm_version=$(nvm ls --no-colors "$nvm_version" | tail -1 | tr -d '\->*' | tr -d '[:space:]')

        # If it is not already installed, install it
        # `nvm install` will implicitly use the newly-installed version
        if [[ "$locally_resolved_nvm_version" == "N/A" ]]; then
            nvm install "$nvm_version";
        elif [[ $(nvm current) != "$locally_resolved_nvm_version" ]]; then
            nvm use "$nvm_version";
        fi
    fi
}
alias cd='cdnvm'
```

#### zsh script

> **Calling `nvm use` automatically in a directory with a `.nvmrc` file**
>   Put this into your `$HOME/.zshrc` to call `nvm use` automatically whenever you enter a directory that contains an `.nvmrc` file with a string telling nvm which node to `use`:

```
# place this after nvm initialization!
autoload -U add-zsh-hook
load-nvmrc() {
  local node_version="$(nvm version)"
  local nvmrc_path="$(nvm_find_nvmrc)"

  if [ -n "$nvmrc_path" ]; then
    local nvmrc_node_version=$(nvm version "$(cat "${nvmrc_path}")")

    if [ "$nvmrc_node_version" = "N/A" ]; then
      nvm install
    elif [ "$nvmrc_node_version" != "$node_version" ]; then
      nvm use
    fi
  elif [ "$node_version" != "$(nvm version default)" ]; then
    echo "Reverting to nvm default version"
    nvm use default
  fi
}
add-zsh-hook chpwd load-nvmrc
load-nvmrc
```

Comment: Hi, @illnr thanks it worked. Can you please tell why do i need
First line -> autoload -U add-zsh-hoo, Lastline -> add-zsh-hook chpwd load-nvmrc it is working fine for me just load-nvmrc function and invoking it only.

Comment: I think this should be the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

NPM now let's you specify the node version for a project like this `npm install node@8`.

So next time you do a `npm ci` or `npm i`, the correct version is automatically set.

Comment: That didn't work for me.  npm -v says the wrong version when I go inside my project.  I have to use nvm use {nodeversion} still and it switches node/npm.   We have engines section which disallows the wrong usage.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ubuntu try below,

```
 "scripts": {
  "prestart": ". ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm use",
   ...
}
```

if you have created `.nvmrc` file then you don't need to specify version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Bash shell, you can define a Bash alias to `cd`, which will do `nvm install` / `nvm use` for you when it detects a `.nvmrc` file.

```
alias cd='function cdnvm(){ cd $@; if [[ -f .nvmrc ]]; then <.nvmrc nvm install; fi; };cdnvm'
```

If you want to make the Node version to revert back to the default when you `cd` out of the directory, use the following alias:

```
alias cd='function cdnvm(){ cd $@; if [[ -f .nvmrc && -s .nvmrc  && -r .nvmrc ]]; then <.nvmrc nvm install; elif [[ $(nvm current) != $(nvm version default) ]]; then nvm use default; fi; };cdnvm'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with using another tool you could use [`nvshim`](https://github.com/iamogbz/nvshim#readme).

```sh
pip install nvshim  # this is all you need to do
```

It does not slow your shell start up, instead moving the lookup of which node version to when you call `node`, `npm` or `npx` by shimming those binaries. More details in the [docs](https://github.com/iamogbz/nvshim#readme).

Source, I wrote the tool.

Comment: this messed with my pm2 installation on ubuntu server 20, and also does some pretty weird stuff on my development machine.. It tries to find a 'default' version but cannot find it, even though the default is aliased with nvm correctly.. Uninstalled after 2 days of trying to fix this issue...

Comment: @Unispaw thanks for the feedback! Should be addressed in [v1.1.2](https://github.com/iamogbz/nvshim/issues/171#issuecomment-1078719002)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution and totally angnostic is to install Directory Enviroment ([direnv](https://direnv.net/)), an extension for your shell. It augments existing shells with a new feature that can load and unload environment variables depending on the current directory.

If you use bash as shell add the following line at the end of the `~/.bashrc` file:

```
eval "$(direnv hook bash)"
```

Instead if you use another shell, simply follow the instructions at this link[enter link description here](https://direnv.net/docs/hook.html)

Then you must add `.envrc` file inside your project and specifies the version you'd like to use:

```
use nodejs 16
```

After thease steps, it will automatically detects and uses the specified version.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm currently using to autoload the node version per project.
It updates a variable for use when node is invoked. It prevents switching node versions for every dir change.

https://gist.github.com/ryanpback/1d0b2808f896398eab6106f49b3e99ab