# Different node version for different projects, is there a way of telling node which version to use?

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, n

I have a pretty common (i guess) problem. Many of my projects utilize nodejs, some for business logic, others only for some building task.

I need to have different runtimes in different projects, one of my electron apps requires node 7.10.0, a typical build suite requires node 8.x.

Now i know - i can use `sudo n 7.10.0` or `sudo n latest` to switch the runtime globally on my computer (For those, who dont know this - have a look at ["n"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n))

Anyway, IMO this is not so convenient (some times, i need to rebuild all the modules after switching versions, often i forget to switch and so on). Is there a way of telling node which interpreter to use? Can i use a `.npmrc` file in a project directory to force a specific nodejs version within that subdirectory?

I searched exactly for this (npmrc node version) but was not lucky enough to find something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, i found a similar quesion:

[Automatically switch to correct version of Node based on project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653036/automatically-switch-to-correct-version-of-node-based-on-project)

it seems you can install "avn" and use a `.node-version` file to do exactly that.

```
sudo npm install -g avn avn-n
avn setup
```

then you can create a .node-version file in your project and enter the desired version

```
echo 7.10.0 > .node-version
```

Then avn will detect that and activate the correct version

Unfortunately i get an additional permissions error. So to make this work, you need to install/configure "n" to work without sudo/root.

Comment: hello, same permission error for me ```checkPermissions Missing write access, Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/avn```. How did you solve that?

Comment: Before installing npm create a file called `.npmrc` and place it inside your home directory. 

the content of that file: `prefix=${HOME}/.npm-packages`

This will make npm install packages to your home directory rather than usr/local...

If you dont want to reinstall everything you can try to fix all kinds of permissions manually. Have a look at the value of your $N_PREFIX environment variable. This is the location your packages are installed. I tried to fix that but ended up with reinstalling everything :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're fine with using another tool you could use [`nvshim`](https://github.com/iamogbz/nvshim#readme).

```sh
pip install nvshim  # this is all you need to do
```

It does not slow your shell startup or switching directories, instead moving the lookup of which node version to when you call `node`, `npm` or `npx` by shimming those binaries. More details in the [docs](https://github.com/iamogbz/nvshim#readme).

Source, I wrote the tool.

Answer (score 0):

**NVM** (Node Version Manager) allow us to use different versions of node quite easily on a single machine. You can have a look at [here](https://www.loginradius.com/blog/async/run-multiple-nodejs-version-on-the-same-machine/) how to configure and use it.

Comment: The link is misleading. It doesn't have any mention of how you used NVM in different projects. @Daud Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

Volta can be used to manage multiple nodejs, npm or yarn versions on different projects on same machine. It's cross-platform.

For example you can run `volta pin node@14` in project directory and this will set node to v14 if it exists otherwise it will download and then set it.

More information here https://docs.volta.sh/guide/

Answer (score 0):

Exact the other version of node in a folder example
`C:\Program files\nodejs_v14_17_0`

Open a PowerShell prompt that you intend to run project on

```
$Env:Path = "C:\Program files\nodejs_v14_17_0;" + $Env:PATH
```

This command prompt will now pick up the alternative nodejs (and npm) for this command prompt only

Then start your program:

```bash
npm start
```