# Maintain same version of npm throughout team

Tags: angular, npm

A colleague just updated some versions in our package.json and we all pulled and ran npm install. When running npm start everyone was fine except for mine, some problem with a load of files about the types being incorrect. 
Eventually I updated my version of npm on my system as mine was behind everyone else and that fixed it.

Is there a way to make sure everyone has the same version of npm installed?

Comment: No, you have to do it by your self. But if you want to use different versions of npm on same machine, you can look into nvm (node version manager)

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case

Comment: I haven't tried this, but you can specify the version of node you need in your package.json file. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349684/how-can-i-specify-the-required-node-js-version-in-packages-json)