# How to install compatible dependencies versions for NodeJs using NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

If I install the latest version of node from nodejs.org, how do I install the dependencies that are compatible with the version.

For example of dependencies:

- material,
- animation,
- cdk,
- flex-layout, etc.

How to install using the npm

Answer (score 0):

Once `node` is installed you can begin using the "node package manager" or `npm`.

First you will need to create a `package.json` file to maintain your packages.

Navigate to the root of your project folder. Ex:

> C/user/repo/my-project

And then initialize the package manager:

```
npm init
```

Follow the onscreen instructions and a `package.json` will appear in this folder.

Now you will be able to install packages.

Here is an example of how to install `material`:

```
npm install material
```

or short hand

```
npm i material
```

This will install the package in the folder you are running the command.

You may want a global install. Installing globally will give all of your projects access to the package. If you want to install it globally try this:

```
npm i -g material
```

> `-g` mean 'global'

Find out more here: https://docs.npmjs.com/

Comment: I am not sure where I should do the npm init  the project folder or web page root folder.  For example I have c:/user/...../NAngular  and I have subfolder C/user .../NAngular/Conf .  If i need to create Conf I need to use ng to create the backbones.  Do I do npm init after creating the Conf directory or before in the NAngular Directory.  Does it matter if I  install the cli first then do the npm init?

Comment: Where should the package.json should be also?

Comment: The package.json goes in the root of your project folder. I updated the answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Many node modules have in their package.json file set on which node version they can work.
You can check [How can I specify the required Node.js version in packages.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349684/how-can-i-specify-the-required-node-js-version-in-packages-json)
 and [npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines) how it is done.

So for example, [@angular/material](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/package.json) has the below in `package.json`:

```
"engines": {
   "node": ">= 5.4.1"
}
```

That means that if you have a version of node that is bigger than `5.4.1` a current version of `@angular/material` is compatible and it will be installed using:

```
npm i @angular/material
```

For detailed information about installing modules using `npm` you can check [npm-install/Install a package](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).