# SyntaxError: Unexpected token, Worked on Windows but not on the VPS, Any Ideas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, vps

#### Issues:

I recently moved my code from a Windows machine to a VPS, everything seemed to be working on my PC, but when I moved to the VPS, I got the following error

```
/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:41
    } catch {
            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js:8:11)
```

#### Environment Details:

I am using Cloud Computing on Ubuntu 18.04 64x

I am using the command handler found here: https://anidiots.guide/first-bot/a-basic-command-handler

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: OP: You need to update Node to version 12 or above.

Comment: @Christian technically, to at least 10. That's where optional catch binding is a thing. However, v12 of discord.js indeed requried node 12 or newer.

Comment: @delta-v you may want to provide the environment details of each server, specifically the node versions in use in both environments, at the time of your initial post.

Answer (score 2):

***Seeing as this question is currently locked, and not accepting new answers, I thought I would address a few observations on the incompatibilities between node versions, all due credit goes to the commenters: @tipakA and @Christian.***

---

There are incompatibilities between versions of Node, it may simply be that you need to update your VPS's version of Node to a later version, one where the `catch` blocks are optional, or more precisely to one which satifies your dependancies, in light of the comment by @tipakA

> v12 of discord.js indeed requried node 12 or newer - @tipakA

In addition to simply upgrading to a compatible version of Node, I would also suggest, you "preserve" the node version as a dependency in your package.json file, like:

```
"engines" : { 
     "node" : ">=0.12" 
}
```

Ensure you, signal that your project will not work at all in lower versions of Node, with this flag

```
"engineStrict" : true
```

Now when you deploy and `npm install`, you will be warned of any discrepancies in Node versions.

> Unfortunately it appears that support for `"engines"` is in flux between npm versions, for example they are deprecated, as of npm 3, but supported in npm v 5x..., so you may want to 'patch/polly-fill' the feature, as outlined in this [article](https://medium.com/@adambisek/how-to-check-minimum-required-node-js-version-4a78a8855a0f), all credit goes to 'Adam Bisek' the author of that article.

Also, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349684/how-can-i-specify-the-required-node-js-version-in-package-json) on StackOverflow, provides additional approaches to the Node version as dependency issue.

---

Alternatively, without having more insight into the stack, or the environment, I have to go with what looks obvious to me.

From the fact that this is throwing a `SyntaxError` I would look at where the `SyntaxError` is. To me the signature of your try catch looks off.

JavaScript has the following signature for a Try/Catch block:

```
try {
  try_statements
}
[catch (exception_var_1 if condition_1) { // non-standard
  catch_statements_1
}]
...
[catch (exception_var_2) {
  catch_statements_2
}]
[finally {
  finally_statements
}]
```

So you would need to have a try catch as such, like this

```
try {

  // attempt to perform something here...

} catch ( e ) {
 
  // do something with "e" or handle the error some how.

}
```

you can read up on this more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).

Comment: This answer is correct for versions of node < 10.0.0.
On 10.0.0 and newer, catch binding is [optional](https://node.green/#ES2019-misc-optional-catch-binding)

Comment: @tipakA, thanks for zeroing in on the heart of the matter, I've updated my answer to incorporate your observations.