# Error installing existing project dependencies with npm install

Tags: npm, npm-install, node-sass

Trying to install dependencies for an existing project on my machine where I'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04. I'm hoping someone can help me understand the problem. Here are what I felt were the most relevant lines from the logs:

```
6003 verbose pkgid node-sass@4.14.1
6004 verbose cwd /home/...
6005 verbose Linux 5.10.60.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
6006 verbose argv "/home/.../.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node" "/home/.../.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/npm" "install"
6007 verbose node v16.14.0
6008 verbose npm  v8.5.0
6009 error code 1
6010 error path /home/.../node_modules/node-sass
6011 error command failed
6012 error command sh -c node scripts/build.js
6013 error Building: /home/.../.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node /home/.../node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=

...

6014 error gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
6014 error gyp info spawn args [
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '/home/.../node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '-f',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   'make',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '/home/.../node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '/home/.../node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '-I',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '/home/.../.node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node/common.gypi',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/.../.node-gyp/16.14.0',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/.../node_modules/node-gyp',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/.../.node-gyp/16.14.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/.../node_modules/node-sass',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   'build',
6014 error gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
6014 error gyp info spawn args ]
6014 error gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 0 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
6014 error gyp ERR! configure error 
6014 error gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
6014 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/home/.../node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
6014 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
6014 error gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
6014 error gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.60.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
6014 error gyp ERR! command "/home/.../.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node" "/home/.../node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
6014 error gyp ERR! cwd /home/.../node_modules/node-sass
6014 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0
6014 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
6014 error gyp ERR! not ok 
6014 error Build failed with error code: 1
```

Here are the dev dependencies in my package.json file in case that's helpful.

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.12.8",
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
        "archiver": "^5.1.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.0.2",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.14",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
        "clean-css-cli": "^4.3.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "csvjson": "^5.1.0",
        "eslint": "^7.14.0",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-standard": "^5.0.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-handlebars": "^5.2.0",
        "glob": "^7.1.6",
        "handlebars": "^4.7.6",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "karma": "^5.2.3",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
        "karma-qunit": "^4.1.1",
        "karma-viewport": "^1.0.7",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
        "pkg-dir": "^5.0.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.1.10",
        "postcss-cli": "^8.3.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "pretty": "^2.0.0",
        "qunit": "^2.12.0",
        "relative": "^3.0.2",
        "resolve": "^1.19.0",
        "resolve-pkg": "^2.0.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "rollup": "^2.33.3",
        "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.4.0",
        "rtlcss": "^2.6.1",
        "sass": "^1.32.0",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "uglify-js": "^3.12.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "xtend": "^4.0.2"
    }
}
```

I deleted my node_modules folder and ran `npm install` and I get this:

```
npm ERR! /home/.../.node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node/v8-internal.h: In function ‘void v8::internal::PerformCastCheck(T*)’:
npm ERR! /home/.../.node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:38: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘remove_cv’?
npm ERR!   492 |             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!       |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!       |                                      remove_cv
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54507679/4113027, created the .nvmrc file with version 14.19.0, then ran `nvm use`. Once I did that I was able to install the dependencies.