# nvm in child process

Tags: node.js, nvm

I'm trying to run a command that depends on nodejs 14 as a child process of my script. For that I use nvm.

Here is my code:

```js
let ex = require("child_process").execSync;

ex( "nvm use 14 & mycommand" );
```

When I launch my script, I get the message "nvm: command not found".

I use zsh on Archlinux.

Please how can I fix my issue ?

Comment: Install `nvm` into the PATH of the user executing the script, perhaps? However this isn’t the right way to set minimum runtime versions - see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349684/how-can-i-specify-the-required-node-js-version-in-package-json)

Comment: Thank you . I can't add nvm to my path, it doesn't correspond to any program in my bin directory. I can't even locate it with `which nvm`. I'm now trying the method in the thread that you suggested.

Comment: Why are you trying to invoke it if you don’t have it installed anywhere…?

Comment: It's installed. Even though the executable is no where, the nvm command is available on my terminal, but not in a script file. Just install nvm by your side, you will see the same strange phenomenon.

Comment: Even the way nvm is installed is strange: you don't just do something like `npm i -g nvm`, you need to download a bizarre script and run it.

Answer (score 3):

Finally this works for me:

```js
ex( "source path/to/nvm.sh && nvm use 14 && mycommand" )
```

Tedious but effective.