# Stop NPM command with message if NPM version is not high enough

Tags: node.js, npm

My svelte project can build on both npm version 6 and 8 but when it is built with version 6  it throws an error on the browser. I can't figure the cause, but I would like to prevent users from running `npm run build` or `npm run dev`.

Is it possible to return from a command showing a message like `The project cannot be built with the current npm version.`?

Comment: You can read this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349684/how-can-i-specify-the-required-node-js-version-in-package-json